# debian /etc/shutdown.allow does not fire when trying to shut down computer

Tags: linux, acl, shutdown

i have a linux box where a remote management application should shut down the box. Those remote management application is running under a normal restrictive user (no root) and the shutdown does just not work.

I have created a file `/etc/shutdown.allow` and entered the name of that restricted user, but when i execute i get this error:

```
myuser/mybox:$ shutdown
command not found
```

also a `shutdown -a` is not recognized and this switch is also not mentioned in the shutdown manual

Is there a way to enable a user or a application running under a restricted user to shutdown the box at all?

INFO: a `sudo shutdown` of course is working from cmd-line, but does not enable the application to shut down the box and i would not be happy to let that application run as root user.

Anybody a idea?
Thank you.

INFO:

```
$ uname -a
Linux mybox 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.51-3 (2017-12-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 8
```

Comment: Maybe `/sbin/shutdown`?

Answer (score 0):

You can only run `shutdown` as `root` user. Maybe you can run this using a `sudo`.